# Threads blocked on reading Zip file

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, jetty, thread-dump

We had a production issue with our Java monolith. Users complained about slowness and site not being available. The thread dump revealed about 400 threads being blocked on a lock obtained by the thread below.

All of these blocked threads have almost the same stacktrace as the blocking thread (+- 1 last frame) - trying to load a VAADIN resource file from the application JAR file.

Does this mean that the thread hanged on reading a static file from a JAR? And others are waiting for one thread to finish reading it?

Anybody have any idea why it happened and how can we prevent this?

Java version: 1.8.0_131

Jetty version: 9.2.z-SNAPSHOT

```
"qtp489279267-42356" #42356 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe7e4054800 nid=0x6f37 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fe776831000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasNext(ZipFile.java:492)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000700002e80> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(ZipFile.java:488)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasNext(JarFile.java:253)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.hasMoreElements(JarFile.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.JarFileResource.exists(JarFileResource.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.getResource(WebAppContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext$Context.getResource(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1276)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.serveStaticResources(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1246)
    at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:423)
    at example.ApplicationServlet.service(ApplicationServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably guessed it right, you seem to be facing contention.

We could look at it from two related perspectives:

1. Lock contention
2. It may not apply to the present use case, but could as well be a problem in a production system under load: I/O contention.

The symptom we have thus far from your stacktrace is what seems to be lock contention.

It seems you are sharing the same *files* (in the sense of Java `ZipFile` objects) across multiple readers reading at the same time. This brings the idea of *caching* - though it may be utterly wrong to think about it depending on your use case, e.g. if you read files of size over one gigabyte.

So, it would be useful to know

1. The total number of files you can read;
2. The median and maximal sizes of these files;
3. The average TTL of these files, i.e. how long they are needed for once loaded in memory;

If we have a reasonable amount of data to cache over any given period of time (i.e. we won't face a spike in demand from clients which would make us need to fetch 1 TB of new data in few seconds) and manage a "relatively small" ad-hoc software system, a straightforward solution could be to cache.

Comment: Well, all the stacktraces where the same - going through Vaadin trying to load resources (static files) from VAADIN folder in the JAR. My main question would be, how it could happen, because usually static files are read quite often by clients (browser), and how can reading a JAR file hang the thread for a long time? (actually just on "exists" method)

Comment: Why would FS be overloaded, when the synchronization is done on Jar File level, that is (if I understood it correctly) multiple processes cannot read the jar in parallel, but they are waiting for each other, otherwise there wouldn't be 400 threads in blocked status. Anyway there is about 20 static files.